# Native Object Oriented Compiler Library

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation, native-code

Lately I've been thinking about writing my own language - something I've wanted to do for some time. I have had some guided experience in writing parsers/compilers for simple languages by using the .Net System.Reflection.Emit library. I really liked using that library, especially because of its focus on object-oriented language design.

The problem is that I would rather it be a native language. So I was wondering: are there any good / simple to use libraries which focus on emitting code for object oriented languages (like System.Reflection.Emit), but would actually emit native code rather than managed code?

Note: I am focused on the actual native code generation, not on parsing. Also, it would be preferable if the library was easily accessible from C++, but any language would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), an open-source C++ library specifically designed for acting as the code-generation backend for portable compilers. It's already in use for the [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) C/C++/ObjC compiler, among other things.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to respond. Thanks for showing me the LLVM project - it's definitely close to what I am looking for. In fact, I think I will be able to make my own thin wrapper around LLVM in order to do precisely what I want.